# Reorganizar index do meu array

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho dois cards na minha aplicação.

O primeiro card possui index 0, o segundo card possui index 1.

Existe uma variável chamada `listAtributos` que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
0: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 5, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Azul"}
1: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}
2: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 6, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Amarelo"}
3: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}
```

Existe uma relação entre o index do card e o indexvariacaoatributo, através dele são mostrados nos meus cards os itens.

Exemplo:

No card 0, por ter index 0, será mostrado através do ngfor os seguintes itens:

```
0: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 5, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Azul"}
1: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}
```

No card 1, por ter index 1, será mostrado através do meu ngfor, os seguintes itens:

```
2: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 6, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Amarelo"}
3: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}
```

Em um determinado momento da minha aplicação eu preciso remover um desses cards, e é nesse momento que os index da minha variável listAtributos fica perdidos.

Tentei fazer um algoritmo para que quando é excluido um card, o indexvariacaoatributo seja atualizado para aparecer no card que sobrou.

Exemplo:

Se eu excluir o card 0, o indexvariacaoatributo dos que estavam 1 devem passar a ser 0.

Se eu excluir o card 1, o indexvariacaoatributo dos que estavam 0 deve passar a ser 1.

Tentei algo como:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.listAtributos.length;i++){
  if(this.listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo == index){
    this.listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo = index - 1;
  }
}
```

a variável index é recebida como parâmetro dessa função, é o index do card a ser excluido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vê se isso te atende. Essa função remove os elementos cujo o *indexvariacaoatributo* for igual ao parâmetro *index* passado e em seguida pega os elementos que possuem *indexvariacaoatributo* a frente do *index* removido e decrementa 1.

```
var array = [
    {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 5, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Azul"},
    {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"},
    {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 6, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Amarelo"},
    {indexvariacaoatributo: 2, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}];

function remover(index, array) {

    let arrayElemRemovido = array.sort((v1, v2) => v1.indexvariacaoatributo > v2.indexvariacaoatributo)
                                 .filter(e => e.indexvariacaoatributo != index)
                                 .map(e => { if (e.indexvariacaoatributo > index) {
                                               e.indexvariacaoatributo -= 1; 
                                             }

                                             return e; 
                                     });
    // Reorganiza os índices para que o primeiro elemento do array seja sempre zero
    while(arrayElemRemovido.length > 0 && arrayElemRemovido.filter(v => v.indexvariacaoatributo == 0).length == 0) {
        arrayElemRemovido.map(v => { v.indexvariacaoatributo -= 1; return v });
    }

    return arrayElemRemovido;

}

var array = remover(0, array);
console.log(array);

/* Saída: 
    0: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 6, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Amarelo"}
    1: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}
*/

var array = remover(1, array);
console.log(array);

/* Saída: 
    0: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 6, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Amarelo"}
*/

var array = [
    {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 5, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Azul"},
    {indexvariacaoatributo: 2, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"},
    {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 6, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Amarelo"},
    {indexvariacaoatributo: 2, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}];

var array = remover(2, array);
console.log(array);

/* Saída: 
    0: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 5, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Azul"}
    1: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 6, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Amarelo"}
*/
```

Comment: Está dando:

Argument of type '(v1: any, v2: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: any, b: any) => number'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.

na linha da função sort

Comment: Tive que fazer alguns ajustes mas sua logica estava correta, conseguiu me ajudar a chegar no meu objetivo. obrigado.

Comment: Esse código que eu postei não é TypeScript, é Javascript. Então talvez precise de algumas poucas adaptações já que a sintaxe é bem semelhante. Porém, você pode copiar esse código inteiro no Console do Google Chrome e executar por lá que você vai ver o algoritmo funcionando. Daí você ajusta para o TS.

Comment: sim, deu certo com os ajustes, a recompensa das 300 reputação fica disponivel em 24h

Comment: Obrigado amigo e boa sorte no seu projeto.

Comment: @RenaotPLS, edita então a resposta do Hélio com os ajustes que você fez, assim a resposta fica valendo 100% para TypeScript, que foi a pergunta original, e pode ajudar outras pessoas que estejam procurando algo parecido.